# Loading Images sequentially in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Suppose I'm making a gallery-like app where you can view a list of images in a long strip. This seems simple enough but I'm encountering a problem where these images are loaded at the same time and (my guess) is that these images are behind some sort of DDoS protection service which prevents me from loading them all at the same time (It gave me 403 errors).

So my solution would be to load them one by one sequentially, however I'm not sure how this could be done in React as I'm quite new to React/React Native in general and communications between sibling components and/or child-parent aren't very straight forward. I've read up on Redux and could this be the solution? - But I've still not got the clear picture on how this can be done either.

For example this is what I have which isn't working

```js
class Gallery extends React.Component {
 
  ...
 
  renderPage(page) { //Each Images
  return (<Page image={page.item}  />)
 }

  ...
  
 render () { 
  return (
   <Container>
    <Header />
     <Content>
      { this.state.isLoading ? <Spinner /> : (
                                // this loads all images at the same time which causes error
        <FlatList 
         initialNumToRender={2}
         data={this.state.pageArray}
         renderItem={this.renderPage}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
         />
       )}
     </Content>
    </Container>
   );
 }
}


export default Gallery;
```

Comment: Have you try `renderItem={({page}) => this.renderPage(page)}`?

Answer (score 1):

**I have tried this on my own, Maybe it will help you a bit.**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';

class Gallery extends Component {
  state = {
    pageArr: [{name: 'abc'}, {name: 'def'}, {name: 'ghi'}],
    isLoading: false,
  };

  renderPage(page) {
    return <Text>{page.name}</Text>;
  }

  render() {
    const {isLoading, pageArr} = this.state;

    return isLoading ? (
      <Spinner />
    ) : (
      <FlatList
        data={pageArr}
        renderItem={({item}) => this.renderPage(item)}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Gallery;
```